# Object as a parameter without declaring a variable

Tags: c#, object, oop, parameters, instance

Why is it possible to create a new object and use it as a parameter WITHOUT declaring "pathVariable"?

```
ExcelPkg.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"D:\New.xlsx"))
```

Otherwise, code below causes an error. Why?

```
package.SaveAs(FileInfo pathVariable = new FileInfo(@"D:\New.xlsx"))
```

Comment: `Why is it possible` Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you're asking why the first *does* work (and why you'd expect it not to) or why the second *doesn't* work. For the latter: you just can't declare a variable within a call like that (other than an `out` variable).

Comment: `Otherwise, code below causes an error. Why?` Because it is invalid. You can't declare a variable _and_ pass it in on the same line like that. Why do you want to do it on one line rather than two?

Comment: First code works because you don't need the variable. The function needs an object as parameter but you don't neet a variable for it if you ONLY use that object there.

Comment: @D.J. and so the compiler gives the object some random name we don't know and don't need to worry about?

Comment: @fysharp yes, no need to worry about it. i tend to avoid this in most cases as this isn't very good for debugging since you don't have the object in a line to investigate or set breakpoints

Comment: The compiler doesn't give the object a name at all, nor does it create a variable. In simple terms, it emits code to instantiate the object, then passes the memory pointer of that object to the `SaveAs` function.

Answer (score 1):

The first question you have to ask yourself is:
"What is a variable anyway?"
Technically a variable is just something that stores the address/position in the heap/stack/memory of an Object that has been created. It's useful becasue you can re-use that same in-memory object multiple times by always saying to the computer "hey i need that exact thingie i used before right here".

But it's not necessary to re-use it, is it? If you just need some data value for that brief micro-/nano-/milisecond, you don't have to remember where you put it.

Think of it as having plates. You can just use paper or any other kind of one-time-use plates for your breakfast meal, or you use the multiple use plates you keep at home in a cupboard of some sort (probably). So when you want to use your favourite plate for breakfast, you have to know where to get it. Did you leave it in the sink? Was it cleaned and put in the cupboard? Did you leave it at your desk? (A "variable" answers that question in your stead, virtually of course).

So why doesn't this work?:

```
package.SaveAs(FileInfo pathVariable = new FileInfo(@"D:\New.xlsx"))
```

bacasue it's a C# syntax error to declare and set a variable in a function parameter. A variable declaration has no place inside a function call.
Well technically, nor does a variable definition. And your example is both of those.

Why does this work?

```
ExcelPkg.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"D:\New.xlsx"))
```

Because it's the same as setting a variable, using it and then throwing it away, like so:

```
FileInfo someTemporaryVariableNameyouDontEvenHaveToRemember = new FileInfo(@"D:\New.xlsx");
ExcelPkg.SaveAs(someTemporaryVariableNameyouDontEvenHaveToRemember);
//Oh, i don't need it anymore
someTemporaryVariableNameyouDontEvenHaveToRemember=null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign and use it as argument if declare somewhere outside:

```
FileInfo pathVariable;
package.SaveAs(pathVariable = new FileInfo(@"D:\New.xlsx"))
```

also as multiple:

```
private void MyMethod()
{ 
    string arg1;
    int arg2;
    bool arg3;

    MyMethod(arg1 = "SomeString", arg2 = 123, arg3 = true);
}

private void MyOtherMethod(string arg1, int arg2, bool arg3)
{ 
    // arg1 will be "SomeString"
    // arg2 will be 123
    // arg1 will be true

    string newArg;

    MyVeryOtherMethod(newArg = arg1.Substring(0, 7)); // "SomeStr"
}

private void MyVeryOtherMethod(string arg)
{ 
    // arg will be "SomeStr"
}
```

I don't saying it is good practice and proper usage. It is possible and only.